# Can GeoTools parse GML CRS definitions?

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, gml

A kind of branching of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3940/how-to-write-gml-with-geotools).

Soon I will need to handle **GML** *Coordinate Reference Sysyem* definitions in a Java servlet. Links:

- [**GML OGC** reference](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml).
- [Concrete  example.](http://kahlua.eecs.jacobs-university.de:8080/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326)

I know that GeoTools library [can parse GML](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/xml/faq.html), and I can see in http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/xml/geometry.html some good documentation regarding `Geometry` features.

I'd like to know whether I will be able to parse such definitions, and maybe translate them to WKT.

Comment: can you clarify? what do you want to do with the CRS, if you just need to identify the projection of the data then GT should be able to handle it fine.

Comment: @iant: Parse the definitions of compound or derived CRS to e.g. understand which dimensions are involved and in which order, then use them to create `CoordinateReferenceSystem` instances (`org.geotools.referencing.CRS` class has a `parseWKT()` method, but not a `parseGML()` equivalent)

Comment: I suspect not then - best place to ask is the user list

Comment: I did that, I'll report any possible hint/answer in case this question remains open.

Comment: The question remains unanswered, I think you should either delete the question or provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present I do not believe that GeoTools can parse the sort of XML CRS definition you have [linked](http://kahlua.eecs.jacobs-university.de:8080/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326) to. I got excited when I found `CRSFactory.createFromXml()` but it throws a "Not Yet Implemented" exception.

However you could probably write a parser with not too much effort as there is already a [`CRSFactory`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/referencing/crs/CRSFactory.html) and others which help with CRS creation from known EPSG codes for example.